# How can i integrate Barcode scanner in my application?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, barcode-scanner

i have sample code of Barcode Scanner but when i install it in my iPhone 2G which contains Version 3.1.3 gives me the below error message.i have taken the code from this link:http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/90FFBB86-DF67-402F-A258-43DFD2BE6794/ScanTest.app/ScanTest
  Reason: image not found

so please give some suggestion or some idea so i can handle it properly and if anybody have any sample code then please give me a link of that i really required it.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The download link that you gave doesnt have a version for iPhone. The error says that it could not find the CoreVideo framework. Core Video framework is not available on iPhones prior to 3GS. It has the video recording functionality that is not available in the earlier versions of the phone. Since you are trying to install it on a 2G phone, the error.

Comment: ok,Thanks Do you have any sample code for barcode scanner i have to use in my application.